# Тонкая рамка border вокруг блока тоньше 1px

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как сделать очень тонкую рамку вокруг блока, чтобы она была визуально тоньше 1px? Понимаю, что по факту тоньше 1px нельзя установить border-width, но может игра цвета или другие свойства помогают получить такой эффект?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так попробовать. В зависимости от нужного цвета, что-то может получиться

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы рамка выглядела тоньше 1px надо поиграть с цветом:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

.b-1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.b-2 {
  border: 1px solid darkgrey;
}

.b-3 {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.b-4 {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

.b-5 {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0;
}

.b-6 {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.b-7 {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-1"><span>border: 1px solid black;</span></div>
<div class="b-2"><span>border: 1px solid darkgrey;</span></div>
<div class="b-3"><span>border: 1px solid grey;</span></div>
<div class="b-4"><span>border: 1px solid lightgrey;</span></div>
<div class="b-5"><span>box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0;</span></div>
<div class="b-6"><span>box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);</span></div>
<div class="b-7"><span>box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 lightgray;</span></div>
```

P.S. Странно, что darkgrey светлее чем просто grey